# Nunit-C#: run specific Tests through coding

Tags: c#, nunit

I am using Selenium with C# for Automation, and I want to invoke NUnit through code as follows:

```
CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(@"D:\Automation\bin\Debug\Test.dll");
RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
//TestFilter filter = new NameFilter(new TestName() { Name = "Test1" });
TestResult testResult = remoteTestRunner.Run(
    new NullListener(),
    TestFilter.Empty,
    false,
    LoggingThreshold.Off
);
```

I am able to run tests using category filter as below

```
remoteTestRunner.Run(
    new NullListener(),
    new CategoryFilter("MyCat"),
    false,
    LoggingThreshold.Off
);
```

But I want to execute specific tests. How do I set the suite filter? I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
TestFilter filter = new NameFilter(new TestName() { Name = "Test1" }); 
TestResult testResult = remoteTestRunner.Run(
    new NullListener(),
    filter,
    false,
    LoggingThreshold.Off
);
```

How do I run specific tests and how do I pass arguments through code?

Comment: If its not possible with NUnit, please suggest me the alternative.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this using a TestName filter? I am trying the same but it keeps coming back Inconclusive?

Answer (score 6):

This sample code should give you an idea of what you have to do to start cycling through your tests and selecting which one you want to run. I have used several array indexes of 0 where you should loop through instead.

The Jist of it is that you have to actually load the tests before you can start trying to run them individually as the tests need to have a unique TestId which only gets set once they have been loaded. The following code works and runs the first test in the first testfixture in your testing framework. It also scans all the test names for you to either display or run based on some criteria

```
CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
TestSuiteBuilder builder = new TestSuiteBuilder();
TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(@"path.to.dll");
RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
TestSuite suite = builder.Build(testPackage);
TestSuite test = suite.Tests[0] as TestSuite;
var numberOfTests = ((TestFixture)test.Tests[0]).TestCount;

foreach (TestMethod t in ((TestFixture)test.Tests[0]).Tests)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.TestName.Name);
}

TestName testName = ((TestMethod)((TestFixture)test.Tests[0]).Tests[0]).TestName;
TestFilter filter = new NameFilter(testName);
TestResult result = test.Run(new NullListener(), filter);
ResultSummarizer summ = new ResultSummarizer(result);
Assert.AreEqual(1, summ.ResultCount);
```

Comment: Worked a dream, thanks. Am now able to look through results too and report back the reason it failed etc.

Comment: Hi @ED-209, Thanks for your response. i am using below code to execute selected tests, its working but, tests executing more times than mentioned.  

SimpleNameFilter filter = new SimpleNameFilter();
foreach (DataRow DR in DT.Rows)
{
string Test = ...;
filter.Add(Test); 
}
       
CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(@"..........dll");
RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
TestResult result = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(), filter, true, LoggingThreshold.All);

Comment: Please give the way to execute selected tests , selected number of times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kishorereddy First I used a NameFilter which took a TestName object. Secondly I ran the test through a TestMethod object, not a RemoteTestRunner. I am not saying it isn't possible, but I know it works as this is what we use to run inividual tests (more than once if necessary). I believe we first tried it your way and ran into the tests all coming back 'Inconclusive'

Comment: @Kishorereddy Glad to hear your tests are working, as for the fact they are executing multiple times. Could this be due to the same test names being used in more than one feature or suite? Maybe NUnit doesn't know which one to choose. I haven't ran into this problem before so don't really know why this would happen. I presumed DataRow is just a list of string test names, maybe you have some duplication in here possibly?

Comment: @ED-209, thanks for your quick response, my input test names string and the DLL are unique[i.e no repeated test cases], when running the code 1st time tests are executing without repetition,if i go for 2nd run 2nd run with the same input tests, those are executing twice and soon....so is there any issue with Nunit assembly loading, else can you tell where the things goes wrong?

Comment: @ED-209,i got the issue, its happening like that bcz of using parametrized TestCases, i have fixed it, Thanks for your support.

Comment: @ED-209, How about ParameterizedMethodSuite?, how we can run Parameterized tests?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code....

```
    SimpleNameFilter filter = new SimpleNameFilter()

    foreach (DataRow DR in DT.Rows)
    {
    string Test = "FullNameOftheTest";
    filter.Add(Test); 
    }

  CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
  TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(@"D:\Test\Test.dll");
  RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
  remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
  TestResult result = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(), filter, true,          LoggingThreshold.All);
  ResultSummarizer summaryResults = new ResultSummarizer(result);
```

Thanks to all for your support,
kishore.

Comment: Is any of this stuff documented by NUnit? I'd like to implement something like this myself but I'd rather RTFM to see what options are open to me

Comment: We don't document it because these are all internal methods, which change from release to release. NUnit has always suffered through the lack of a published API to run tests. NUnit 3.0 provides such an API. Rough documentation is available at https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Test-Engine-API and will be moved under https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki when it is complete.