# Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'NUnit.Core.NamespaceSuite' to type 'NUnit.Core.TestFixture'

Tags: c#, nunit-2.6

I am getting a typecast exception while executing the below code :

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{            
    string testpackagepath = @"C:\Users\pjena\source\repos\Lacerte.Test\Lacerte.Test.Nunit\bin\Debug\Lacerte.Test.Nunit.dll";

    CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
    TestSuiteBuilder builder = new TestSuiteBuilder();
    TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(testpackagepath);
    RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
    remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);

    TestSuite suite = builder.Build(testPackage);
    TestSuite test = suite.Tests[0] as TestSuite;
    var numberOfTests = ((TestFixture)test.Tests[0]).TestCount;

    foreach (TestMethod t in ((TestFixture)test.Tests[0]).Tests)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.TestName.Name);
    }

    TestName testName = ((TestMethod)((TestFixture)test.Tests[0]).Tests[0]).TestName;
    TestFilter filter = new NameFilter(testName);
    TestResult result = test.Run(new NullListener(), filter);
    ResultSummarizer summ = new ResultSummarizer(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, summ.ResultCount);
}
```

Error I am getting:

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'NUnit.Core.NamespaceSuite' to type 'NUnit.Core.TestFixture'."

I was trying one answer give in this forum and landed into this problem [Nunit-C#: run specific Tests through coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216011/nunit-c-run-specific-tests-through-coding)

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Somewhere in there you tried to cast a NamespaceSuite object to a `TestFixture`. Debug your code and check the line that throws. Check the *value* of the object you tried to cast into a TestFixture in the Watch window and fix your code.

Comment: _in this forum_ - SO/SE are not forums.

Comment: BTW 2.6 is very, very, very old. Are you *really* targeting such an old version?

Comment: Furthermore, please clean this up. You are calling `(TestFixture)test.Tests[0]` all over the place - just store the value in a variable and reuse it. If that line throws, you'll know what was wrong too. Check the object's type *before* trying to cast it, either by using `is` or `as`

Comment: PS the contents of the Tests property of a TestSuite depend on *your* tests. It's impossible for others to reproduce the error. The only advice one can give is to check the value's type before casting

Comment: Maybe stupid question: Why are you coding your own test runner? There's an Nunit console for that.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I used TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name to get the test names and I am able to get my job done.

Comment: I am trying to integrate running a test case from my desktop application itself. So I am trying to run my own test Runner.

Comment: W.r.t the older version of .Net Yes mee too concerned. I am not able to find a equivalent of test runner in .Net 3. Can anyone please suggest a .Net 3 equivalent of the below code

Comment: {CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
            TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(testpackagepath);
            RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
            remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
            TestResult testResult = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(), TestFilter.Empty, false, LoggingThreshold.All);}